# is it possible to remove index.php in url without htaccess?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Is it possible in any way to remove index.php in url without using **.htaccess**

1. if yes then how.
2. and if not then how to make **htaccess** file in **xampp** server.
3. how to apply this in live server.

i tried to make through class but i think it is not possible but i want to be sure so please help me on this ...

what i find is something like 
$route['(:any)'] = 'index.php/$1';
in htccess every where so i believe it is not possible because it is something doing nothing with php or any language it is server thing and only chance or way we have is htaccess

Comment: You don't need htaccess, you need a rewrite module (mod_rewrite for Apache).  htaccess is just Apache's way of allowing you to specify virtualhost configuration in the working directory.

Comment: What is your problem with creating htaccess on xampp?